# Incorrectly read data in ts function in R

Tags: r, time-series

I want to convert a dataframe from a CSV to a ts object, but the conversion process gives strange values which do not correspond at all to the original ones. This makes no sense. All I am doing is:

```
library(data.table)
data=fread('data.csv', select=c('Volume'))
datats=ts(data,frequency=365)
```

This is the original data:

```
2507945867
1547207565
1229821215
1585032040
2179651359
1415340765
994520516
679602960
690703669
```

But when converted to ts, I get

```
1.616122e-314
1.239090e-314
7.644221e-315
6.076124e-315
7.831099e-315
1.076891e-314
6.992712e-315
4.913584e-315
3.357685e-315
3.412530e-315
```

What is going on? I am fairly new to R so I do not understand this behaviour at all...

Comment: can you explain the original data a bit? What do the values look like the csv before you import them?

Comment: Why not use `read.csv` or `readr::read_csv` ?